# dplyr: min function in summarise function causes R crash

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an empty `tbl_df` as a result of `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tbl_df(data.frame(A=c(1)))
df <- df %>% filter(A > 1)
```

I want to `summarise` the this degenerate case of `tbl_df`:

```
df %>% summarise(Mean=mean(A, na.rm=T))
```

This works fine:

```
Source: local data frame [1 x 1]

  Mean
1  NaN
```

But `min` function causes crash:

```
df %>% summarise(Min=min(A, na.rm=T))
```

In RStudio it would terminate the R session, but in R command line I got more details:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xb8599d8, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("dplyr_summarise_impl", PACKAGE = "dplyr", df, dots)
 2: summarise_impl(.data, dots)
 3: summarise_.tbl_df(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
 4: summarise_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))
 5: summarise(., Min = min(A, na.rm = T))
 6: function_list[[k]](value)
 7: withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
 8: freduce(value, `_function_list`)
 9: `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
10: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
11: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
12: withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
13: df %>% summarise(Min = min(A, na.rm = T))

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

I have similar crash with `max`, I don't know if there are more functions in trouble.

My `dplyr` version is `0.4.2`, R version is `3.2.2`, OS is Ubuntu 14.04. Please let me know if my problem is reproducible, and is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Same behavior with `dplyr` version `0.4.3`.

Comment: Segfaults are always bugs. You should report this to the dplyr development team.